# In this case "where" clause does not work in memsql

Tags: mysql, encoding, where-clause, singlestore

I have load data from MySQL into MemSQL v6.0-beta successfully by

```
CREATE TABLE ashareeodprices (
 OBJECT_ID  varchar(38),
 S_INFO_WINDCODE    varchar(40),
 TRADE_DT   varchar(8),
 CRNCY_CODE varchar(10),
 S_DQ_PRECLOSE  double,
 S_DQ_OPEN  double,
 S_DQ_HIGH  double,
 S_DQ_LOW   double,
 S_DQ_CLOSE double,
 S_DQ_CHANGE    double,
 S_DQ_PCTCHANGE double,
 S_DQ_VOLUME    double,
 S_DQ_AMOUNT    double,
 S_DQ_ADJPRECLOSE   double,
 S_DQ_ADJOPEN   double,
 S_DQ_ADJHIGH   double,
 S_DQ_ADJLOW    double,
 S_DQ_ADJCLOSE  double,
 S_DQ_ADJFACTOR double,
 S_DQ_AVGPRICE  double,
 S_DQ_TRADESTATUS   varchar(10),
 OPDATE datetime,
 OPMODE varchar(1)
)
```

and

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/ashareeodprices.csv' INTO TABLE ashareeodprices
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

then

```
SELECT * FROM ashareeodprices;
SELECT * FROM ashareeodprices WHERE S_DQ_LOW=0;
```

These SQL statements work fine in MySQL and MemSQL both. But in this case  it does not.

```
SELECT * FROM ashareeodprices WHERE S_INFO_WINDCODE='600031.SH';
```

In MySQL it works. In MemSQL it returns

```
Empty set
```

I think the problem is about encoding. What is wrong about '600031.SH'?

Comment: Show us your schema. May be there is sometime engine compatibility issues.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong here.  Can you check the file and make sure that value is actually in there.  Have you tried `select s_info_wincode from ashareeodprices limit 10` to see if the data in that column looks at least somewhat reasonable?

Comment: SELECT S_INFO_WINDCODE FROM asharedescription LIMIT 10; returns a list, even if I pick one, SELECT * FROM asharedescription WHERE S_INFO_WINDCODE="A14650.SH"; It return empty set;